# How to fill the remainder of a Bootstrap column with an input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an input inside a Bootstrap column like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <input />
</div>
```

I need to add a small amount of text next to the input, and I want the input to fill the remaining space in the column after the text.

I've written this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    Hello <input />
</div>
```

This completely breaks the page layout as the input gets bumped over to the next column.

How can I make it so that the text "Hello" appears at the beginning of the column and the input fills the remaining space without spilling into the next column?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways. For example, in Bootstap 4, you can use `d-flex` for `display:flex`.

```
<div class="col-2 d-flex">
      Hello <input />
</div>
```

In older 3.x, you would do this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
      Hello <input />
</form>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/lb0rWUEpMK